# How to add the ref for the render function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to add the ref for the render function?

I have a `custom_modal` util for show a custom modal in `util.js`:

```
util.custom_modal = function (context ) {

  context.$Modal.info({
    render: (h) => {
      return h('div', {

      },[
        h('div', {props: {ref:"abc"}, attrs: {} }, 'ABC')
      ])
    }
  })
```

when I in a component to use the modal util, the `this.$refs` do not have the `abc` ref.

```
util.custom_modal(this)
```

in the Browser `console` I type `this.$refs`, do not have a `abc` ref.

In the render function I also put the ref to the attrs:

```
h('div', {props: {}, attrs: {ref:"abc"} }, 'ABC')
```

It still not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `ref` directly (*not* as an attribute):

```
h('div', {props: {}, ref:"abc"}, 'ABC')
```

Another example, a

```
<input type="text" ref="foobar">
```

Would be:

```
h('input',{ref:"foobar",attrs:{"type":"text"}})
```

**Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  render(h) {
    return h('input',{ref:"foobar",attrs:{"type":"text"}})
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('My foobar input:', this.$refs.foobar);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```